# Nested Array defined by window.prompt is not updating view using .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, arrays

New to JavaScript and wanted to learn about how event listeners and window.prompts work so I decided to build something.

Before I say anything else, I have tried to create a new array instead of a nested array to determine if that was the problem. I also console.logged succesfully the nested array which returned 'undefined'.

After line 14 of the JS file, which is where the first value of myCompany[0][0] is defined via window.prompt is where the code ceases to run any further. This is what the console log says in regards to line 14.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at companyPush (scripts.js:13)

Also here is the HTML and JS. There is no CSS (not that it matter... i think).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Arrays and that</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Profile</h2>
    <p></p>

    <h2>Experience</h2>
    <ul id="companyOne">
    <li id="companyOneResponsibilitiesOne"></li>
    <li id="companyOneResponsibilitiesTwo"></li>
    <li id="companyOneResponsibilitiesThree"></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="companyTwo">
    <li id="companyTwoResponsibilitiesOne"></li>
    <li id="companyTwoResponsibilitiesTwo"></li>
    <li id="companyTwoResponsibilitiesThree"></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="companyThree">
    <li id="companyThreeResponsibilitiesOne"></li>
    <li id="companyThreeResponsibilitiesTwo"></li>
    <li id="companyThreeResponsibilitiesThree"></li>
    </ul>


    <h2>Skills</h2>
    <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Favorite Foods</h2>
    <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the JS.

```
    window.addEventListener("load", function companyPush() {

        // declare new variable = new array
        var myCompany = new Array;  
        // Window prompts fill array data
        document.getElementById("companyOne").innerHTML = myCompany[0] = window.prompt("Where is your most recent place of work?");
        document.getElementById("companyTwo").innerHTML = myCompany[1] = window.prompt("Where did you work before that?");
        document.getElementById("companyThree").innerHTML = myCompany[2] = window.prompt("And before that?");

        // declare nested array with 'oldArray["newArrayName"]'
        myCompany[0][0] = new Array;
        // Window prompts fill nested array data
        document.getElementById("companyOneResponsibilitiesOne").innerHTML = myCompany[0][0] = window.prompt("1");
        document.getElementById("companyOneResponsibilitiesTwo").innerHTML = myCompany[0][1] = window.prompt("2");
        document.getElementById("companyOneResponsibilitiesThree").innerHTML = myCompany[0][2] = window.prompt("3");

});
```

I hope this is sufficient information.

What is supposed to happen is the document.getElementById("companyOneResponsibilitiesOne").innerHTML is supposed to update the relevant HTML depending on what they type in on the window.prompt.

Let me know if you need more info.

Changed JS as per Jonathons suggestion.

```
    window.addEventListener("load", function companyPush() {

        // declare new variable = new array
        var myCompany = new Array;  
        myCompany[0] = new Array;
        // Window prompts fill array data
        document.getElementById("companyOne").innerHTML = myCompany[0][1] = window.prompt("Where is your most recent place of work?");
        document.getElementById("companyTwo").innerHTML = myCompany[0][2] = window.prompt("Where did you work before that?");
        document.getElementById("companyThree").innerHTML = myCompany[0][3] = window.prompt("And before that?");

        // declare nested array with 'oldArray["newArrayName"]'
        myCompany[1] = new Array;
        // Window prompts fill nested array data
        document.getElementById("companyOneResponsibilitiesOne").innerHTML = myCompany[1][0] = window.prompt("1");
        document.getElementById("companyOneResponsibilitiesTwo").innerHTML = myCompany[1][1] = window.prompt("2");
        document.getElementById("companyOneResponsibilitiesThree").innerHTML = myCompany[1][2] = window.prompt("3");

});
```

Comment: Do you know how I would get around this to update via window.prompt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try providing another `Array` for the first 3 prompts, so that each set of prompts has its own. You may also consider also giving each set its own variable (`setOne`, `setTwo`, etc. in this case) for easier reference.

```
var myCompany = new Array;             // parent array holding all sets
var setOne = myCompany[0] = new Array; // 1st set of prompts

document.getElementById("companyOne").innerHTML = setOne[0] = window.prompt("Where is your most recent place of work?");
document.getElementById("companyTwo").innerHTML = setOne[1] = window.prompt("Where did you work before that?");
// ...

var setTwo = myCompany[1] = new Array; // 2nd set of prompts

document.getElementById("companyOneResponsibilitiesOne").innerHTML = setTwo[0] = window.prompt("1");
document.getElementById("companyOneResponsibilitiesTwo").innerHTML = setTwo[1] = window.prompt("2");
// ...
```

---

Currently, `myCompany[0]` is being assigned a string value that's return from `prompt()`. Strings define their own indexes as references to individual characters.

```
var myCompany = [ 'example' ];
console.log(myCompany[0][0]); // 'e'
console.log(myCompany[0][1]); // 'x'
console.log(myCompany[0][2]); // 'a'

// same as...
console.log(myCompany[0].charAt(0)); // 'e'
```

Strings are also immutable, so their indexes/characters can't be changed and any assignments to them are ignored.

```
myCompany[0][0] = new Array;
console.log(myCompany[0][0]); // 'e' (no change)
```

Comment: Give me a moment while I try to implement this

Comment: I have added what I have done in the original question - it has better formatting

Comment: @MuhammadAli The one issue that stands out in your comment is that `my company` is listed with a space in some cases rather than always as `myCompany` (guessing that's just a typo). Are any errors occurring? Or, what result does it give you? Can you elaborate any on "does not work?"

Comment: In the console this is being printed:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at companyPush (scripts.js:14)

Yes, it is a typo. In the code it is referred to in all places as myCompany. 

Also, the window prompts are successful for the first three prompts, after the 4th prompt '("1")'. The code stops running and only the first three values from the prompts are printed in the relevant places.

Comment: @MuhammadAli Ah. Since `companyOne` refers to the `<ul>`, when you set its `innerHTML`, that first removes all of its `<li>`s and replaces them with only the text from the prompt. It can't find the `<li>`s later since they're no longer within the document. – To resolve that, you could revise the markup so they aren't directly parent-children. Here one option: https://jsfiddle.net/mgze11j7/ (using constants rather than the prompts just for brevity).

Comment: Thank you, this would have taken me forever to figure out.